# OleDbException was unhandled C# to access database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I am using an Access database with a table called Contact. The table contains these fields 
ContactID,   FirstName, LastName, SpouseName, Phone,    Email, WeddingDate, StreetAddress, Suburb, City, PostCode, Country and Comments. ContactID is an AutoNumber and the PK and WeddingDate is date/time. All the rest are text fields.

I have a simple form with 4 text boxes on it for the firstName, LastName, Phone, and Email with a save button. Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project1
{
public partial class DataSource : Form
{
    OleDbConnection connection=new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Wills\Projects\Windows\project1\project1\project1.accdb");
    public DataSource()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void DataSource_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vsql = string.Format("INSERT INTO Contact values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Phone, @Email)", txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text);
        OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, connection);
        vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data store successfully");
        vcom.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Close();
        this.Close();
    }          
}
}
```

I am getting the error on the line vcom.ExecuteNonQuery(); saying "OleDbException was unhandled  No value given for one or more required parameters."

I have tried to change the insert statement but with no luck and looking at other examples on the forum I cannot get any of the changes to work with my solution. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this line from your code.

```
string vsql = string.Format(
        "INSERT INTO Contact values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Phone, @Email)",
        txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text);
```

The result is `INSERT INTO Contact values(@FirstName, @LastName, @Phone, @Email)`.

I think you're looking for this.

```
string vsql = string.Format(
        "INSERT INTO Contact values('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", 
        txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text);
```

Also, if you are trying to insert into specific columns, you'll need to use a different insert code. Try this.

```
string vsql = string.Format(
        "INSERT INTO Contact (FirstName, LastName, Phone, Email) " + 
        "values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", 
        txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtEmail.Text);
```

Comment: Hi @Jieqin unfortunately it is still giving me the same message. Any more ideas? Thanks for your help though

Comment: Could you place a breakpoint at the line `OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(vsql, connection);`? Then point at the respective `_____.Text` and see their values? Also, please check your database structure/design to confirm that you have **exactly** 4 columns within that table.

Comment: I have done that and they all have the text that I put in the form showing as the values

Comment: I don't have 4 columns in the table. See the top of the question where I list the table and all the columns

Comment: Ah, so that's the problem there. If you merely want to insert into specific columns, you have to use a different insert code. I'll update the answer.